# Question on graph Connectivity.

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, connectedness, eulerian-path, graph-connectivity

### Question

> Consider the statement below-:

$\text{1.In simple graph with 6 vertices,if degree of each vertex is 2 ,then graph is connected}$

$\text{2.In simple graph with 6 vertices,if degree of each vertex is 2 ,then graph is Euler}$

$\text{3.In simple graph ,if degree of each vertex is 3 ,then graph is connected}$

### My Approach

$1.\text{Using Handshaking lemma,}$

$2+2+2+2+2+2=2 \times |Edges| $

$\text{number of Edges}=6$

Thus a **simple graph** having $6$ vertices and $6$edges and each having degree $2$  will be connected because it will also be a simple cycle.

---

$2.$As graph is connected and degree of each vertex is even ,thus it will be a
[Eulerian graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path)

---

$3.$ If degree of each vertex is $3$ , then we cannot say anything about its connectivity.
It may be connected or disconnected.

Am i correct?
I am not sure about $3$.
Please help

Comment: Why downvote to my question ? Have i represented question bad?Have i asked a homework question? Am i asking directly for a answer ?Well i have represented it well +shown all my work+asking for a hint.If still someone(who downvoted) thinks it is a bad framed question , then please comment your valuable suggestion so that i will not repeat it again .Downvoting --> you are smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to all cases are "not necessrily". An example for the first two questions is a disjoint union of two triangles $K_3$, and for the third a disjoint union of two tetrahedra $K_4$.

Comment: Yes you are correct .but how to derive your example mathematically ? I mean I have $n$ vertex $n$ edges and degree of each vertex is $2$ All are the properties of simple cycle.

Comment: @laura These properties are necessary for a cycle, but not sufficient. They are necessary and sufficient conditions for a disjoint union of cycles.

Comment: ok thanks a lot